# compton config for transparency in i3's tabbed/stacked mode

Tags: i3-wm, compton, zathura

I am trying to:

1. make some applications transparent using `compton` on `i3wm` such that
2. in tabbed/ stacked mode in `i3wm` the underlying windows are hidden (or are not drawn).

For example's sake, let us take the application to be `zathura`.

I tried the following in my `compton.conf`:

```
opacity-rule = [
"90:class_g = 'Zathura' && !_NET_WM_STATE@:32a",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
]
```

This doesn't make `zathura` transparent, but `zathura` is hidden if it is beneath any other transparent window in tabbed/ stacked window.

Next I tried the following in `compton.conf`:

```
opacity-rule = [
"90:class_g = 'Zathura'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
]
```

This does make `zathura` transparent, but this draws `zathura` beneath other windows when in tabbed or stacked mode in `i3wm`.

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281131/compton-i3-tabbed-stacked-transparency-background-image) and tried the suggested solution. That is, I replaced `"0:_NET_WM_STATE@:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"` with

```
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[0]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[1]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[2]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[3]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'",
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[4]:32a = '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
```

However this made no change. Please help.

=========================================

My entire `compton.conf` is as follows:

```
menu        = { shadow = false; };
dropdown_menu = { shadow = false; };
popup_menu    = { shadow = false; };
utility       = { shadow = false; };

# Shadow
shadow = true;
no-dnd-shadow = true;
no-dock-shadow = true;
clear-shadow = true;
shadow-radius = 7;
shadow-offset-x = -7;
shadow-offset-y = -7;
shadow-exclude = [
       "class_g = 'i3-frame'",
       "class_g = 'keynav'",           
       "name = 'Notification'",
       "class_g ?= 'Notify-osd'",
       "_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS@:c"
];


opacity-rule = [
# "90:class_g = 'Zathura'",
"90:class_g = 'Zathura' && !_NET_WM_STATE@:32a",

# "0:_NET_WM_STATE@:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[0]:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
,"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[1]:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
,"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[2]:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
,"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[3]:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
,"0:_NET_WM_STATE@[4]:32a *= '_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN'"
];

# Fading
fading = true;
fade-delta = 5;
fade-in-step = 0.03;
fade-out-step = 0.03;
fade-exclude = [ ];

# Other
backend = "xrender";
mark-wmwin-focused = true;
mark-ovredir-focused = true;
detect-rounded-corners = true;
detect-client-opacity = true;
refresh-rate = 0;
vsync = "none";
dbe = false;
focus-exclude = [ "class_g = 'Cairo-clock'" ];
detect-transient = true;
detect-client-leader = true;
invert-color-include = [ ];

# GLX backend
glx-copy-from-front = false;
glx-swap-method = "undefined";

# Window type settings
wintypes:
{
  tooltip = { fade = true; shadow = true; opacity = 0.75; focus = true; };
};
```